# prisma any good if i need mysql view and stored procedures in nextJS

Tags: next.js, prisma

I'm starting to learn prisma to replace my nodejs back-end in my nextJS app.

It seems that prisma is not made to work with views and stored procedures created in my mysql database.

Is there even a point in switching to prisma if I cannot just use views and stored procedures, which allows me to create a user in the database that can only access those two and nothing else.

any prisma pro's that could give confirm or deny what I am thinking

Thx

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While neither feature is *directly* supported by Prisma at the moment, workarounds exist that make it possible to use both with Prisma. For both you would need to perform some operations directly in SQL.

### Stored Procedures

You can use the `$executeRaw` and `$queryRaw` command to perform raw SQL queries through Prisma. You can use this to execute your created procedures. For example, if you have a stored procedure called `foobar`  you could execute it as follows:

```js
  const rawSQL = `call foobar`;
  const result = await prisma.$executeRaw(rawSQL);
```

You could also use `$executeRaw` to *generate* the stored procedure or use the tool/CLI of your choice.

Check out the [Raw database access article](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/raw-database-access#executeraw) for more information on  `$executeRaw` and `$queryRaw`, as well as the difference between the two.

### MySQL View

A workflow exists to use views through Prisma. The workflow goes something like this:

1. Create the view directly using SQL.
2. Introspect database to update your Prisma Schema.
3. *Manually* add the model for your view to the Prisma Schema.
4. Generate the Prisma client and use the entity class created for the view to run queries.

You can find a indepth guide on [how to use SQL Views in MySQL](https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/database/advanced-database-tasks/sql-views-mysql) along with discussions and current limitations.

#### Suggestions

For both features, I would strongly suggest *trying out your usecase first* before adopting Prisma in a production application. For example, in the past users have faced some difficulties when running procedures that [return data back to the client](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/2208) (this should be fixed now though).

Additionally, if you face any issues or bugs, always feel to [create a issue](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/new/choose) on the Prisma github repo. We are super active and will try our best to help fix the issue.

Comment: related if you are using typescript https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69564787/nestjs-postgres-prisma-error-type-string-is-not-assignable-to-parameter-type