# Prisma ORM- create stored procedure

Tags: node.js, prisma

Using Prisma client 3 I'm trying to create a stored procedure.

The motivation behind it is:

- I need to query a table that will be created on run time.
- To do this, I need to use dynamic queries,
  and I read that stored procedures will be the better practice in this case (pass the table name as a parameter).
- I would like for each member of my team to have the updated version of the stored procedure (like all the tables in Prisma)

So, what I've decided to do is to create the stored procedure with `prisma.$executeRaw` when the app starts and call it when I need.

The code:
let prisma = new PrismaClient();

```
let res = await prisma.$executeRawUnsafe(`
  CREATE PROCEDURE \`module-events\`.GetAllProducts()
  BEGIN
    select 555;
  END
`);
```

The result:

```
Invalid `prisma.$executeRaw()` invocation:

Raw query failed. Code: `1295`. Message: `This command is not supported in the prepared statement protocol yet`
```

As you can see the `$executeRawUnsafe()` returns the same results. Is there any way to create a stored procedure with Prisma? Is there a way to run a "free style" query that is not limited by Prisma?

I understood from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68417950/8597762) answer that it is possible to create the stored procedure:

> You could also use $executeRaw to generate the stored procedure or use the tool/CLI of your choice.

Comment: There are numerous examples I could find which allowed calling a stored procedure, but I wasn't able to find one which created a stored procedure. Based on this Feature Request: https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/3337 It seems that creating stored procedure isn't supported yet.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do something like this to  write a SQL query:

```
await this.prisma.$queryRaw(
  Prisma.sql`EXEC [dbo].[Spname]`,
);
```

This is an example of the Exec SP but try create as well.